# Async / await pattern c# and wp8 but AsyncLock is really need?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, locking, async-await

Hi I've try to find where and when use an async lock, but I've not found any way to write an effective example. following there's an example, but no conflicts so

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Debug.WriteLine("Start");
            test1();
            test2();
            Debug.WriteLine("End");
        }
        async void test1() {

            Debug.WriteLine("Start------------------");
            for (var a = 0; a < 100; a++)
            {

                var r = await TaskExample.GetSumAsync(3, 5);
                if (r != 8)
                    Debug.WriteLine("-->" + r);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("End--------------------");
        }

        async void test2() { 


            for (var a = 0; a < 100; a++)
            {

                var r = await TaskExample.GetSubAsync(8, 4);
                if (r != 4)
                    Debug.WriteLine("-->" + r);
            }


        }
```

here's the class

```
namespace TestTask
{
    class TaskExample
    {
        static int ta=0;
        static int tb = 0;

        public static Task<int> GetSumAsync(int a, int b) {

            return Task<int>.Run(new Func<int>(() =>
            {

                 ta = a + 100;
                 tb = b;

                  ta -= 100;


                return ta + tb;
            }));

        }

        public static Task<int> GetSubAsync(int a, int b)
        {

            return Task<int>.Run(new Func<int>(() =>
            {

                ta = a + 100;
                tb = b;

                ta -= 100;


                return ta - tb;
            }));

        }

    }

}
```

so this never fails, so my question there's a simple example that fail and I really need to use AsyncLock or other kind of "barrier" or "lock"?

Thanks

update:

the real point is this: my example, according my point of view, should fail without use of asynclock, but instead it works! Ok my question is to give me an example of code when I Must use AsyncLock because I not able to write one, so I'm not able to understand when use it 
thanks :)

Comment: Think about any time you'd use a `lock` in synchronous code.  You'd use an `AsyncLock` when writing that same code asynchronously.  It's pretty much that simple.  Oh, and you should avoid `async void` methods; only use them when you absolutely *must*.  Unless you have no choice, the methods should return a `Task`.

Comment: Side note: the problem with code that *must* have `lock` (or any other synchronization) but does not use it is it *may* work perfectly fine everywhere except in some particular timing/configuration - like work fine on machines with even number of cores and fail on ones with odd number of cores... Basically "it works" does not mean much for code that ignores/does not implemnt protection of shared data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use many tasks to increment a shared counter, and verify the final count. Incrementing is a load-calculate-store cycle which is not atomic. You will find lost updates.

```
int iterationsPerThread = 10 * 1000000;
var taskCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;

int counter = 0;

var tasks =
    Enumerable.Range(0, taskCount)
    .Select(_ => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterationsPerThread; i++)
        {
            counter = counter + 1; //racy!
        }
    }))
    .ToArray();

Task.WaitAll(tasks); //quiece system

Console.WriteLine("Expected: " + (iterationsPerThread * taskCount));
Console.WriteLine("Actual: " + counter);
```

I get:

```
Expected: 80000000
Actual:   22799012 //about 75% of increments lost
```

This is not different than non-await and non-TPL code.